# Usando vistas de mapas con Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone

Tengo una aplicación en la cual necesito incrustar un Mapa. Se que está el control map desde la toolbox. Solo que no se como cambiar la vista del mapa dependiendo el tipo que quiera el usuario. ¿Alguién sabe como?

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir más detalles? Quizás algo de código o lo que se espera que ocurra ayudaría a los usuarios a identificar y contestar mejor esta pregunta

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este link http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, . Saludos

Comment: Si, me refería a la cartografía como en la respuesta de Víctor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no estoy seguro si te refieres las vistas Cartograficas. Si es así, imaginemos que tienes tres CheckBox, y por cada uno tienes una vista diferente en tu mapa:

```
private void Road_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(MyMap!=null)
        MyMap.CartographicMode = MapCartographicMode.Road;
}

private void Aerial_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(MyMap!=null)
        MyMap.CartographicMode = MapCartographicMode.Aerial;
}

private void Hybrid_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(MyMap!=null)
        MyMap.CartographicMode = MapCartographicMode.Hybrid;
}

private void Terrain_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(MyMap!=null)
        MyMap.CartographicMode = MapCartographicMode.Terrain;
}
```

Tampoco olvides agregar el namespace:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad, si lo es. Marcale palomita :)

Comment: Ándale, de eso hablaba. Solo que desconocía el nombre específico "Cartografía".